# Eexpand 2 more Titledpanes at once

Tags: swing, javafx, accordion, jfxpanel

On these days i am refactoring java swing code to javafx.
And about some jpanels, i just refactored as JFXPanel and that JFXPanels` root is VBOX. the structure of JFXPanel is VBOX -> BorderPane -> TitledPane -> AnchorPane.

```
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="93.0" prefWidth="295.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="259.0" prefWidth="309.0">
         <top>
            <TitledPane animated="false" prefHeight="93.0" prefWidth="297.0" style="-fx-background-color: #eeeeee;" text="Compensation Options" textFill="#1b75bc">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="295.0" prefWidth="267.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="mResetCountButton" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reset Counts" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                        <Button fx:id="plotStatsButton" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stats Panel" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                        <Button fx:id="gateStatsButton" layoutX="208.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Gate State" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                        <Button fx:id="mLoadMatrixButton" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="37.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Load Matrix" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                        <Button fx:id="viewCompMatrix" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="37.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="View Matrix" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                        <Label fx:id="mJCompMatrixCombo" layoutX="208.0" layoutY="41.0" text="Matrix Name" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

And now i want to make JFXPanels as Accordion. When i searched in google i just saw some code which use  and when i make Accordion tag, i just can use TitledPane below tag.
Is there any other way to make JFXPanels as Accordion reusing my code?...

And actually using  Tag, i just can expand one titledPane at once.
How can i make JavaFX application with Accordion which can expand many titledPanes at once?

I just tried as make titledPanes`clicklistener and resizing VBox which is wrapping titledPane and titledpane`s size and some panes which in inside of titledpane.

such as

```
boolean titledPaneClicked = false;

TiteldPane.setOnAction((e)->{
    if(titledPaneClicked){
        TitledPane.setHeight(0);
        Vbox.setHeight(0);
        soemotherPanes.setHeight(0);
        titledPaneClicked = !titledPaneClicked;
    }else{
        TitledPane.setHeight(previousSize);
        Vbox.setHeight(previousSize);
        soemotherPanes.setHeight(previousSize);
        titledPaneClicked = !titledPaneClicked;
    }
});
```

And it did not work. Plz help me :)

Comment: @Sedrick Actually, i want to make Accordion can expand 2 more titledpanes at once...

Comment: "The structure of JFXPanel is VBOX -> BorderPane -> TitledPane -> AnchorPane"  please do not describe the code. Post it. See [mcve]

Comment: @c0der Okay. I modified about it.

Comment: Please read about mcve in the link provided. If it is not clear ask for clarifications. Preparing an mcve should also clarify your need which is not clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how you can open close 2 `TitledPane`s at once, you can do so programmatically, for example by using a button :

**Main.fxml**  (to make your code mcve always post the fxml name and imports)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="tests.xml.Controller">
   <children>
      <BorderPane>
         <top>
            <TitledPane fx:id="aTitledPane" animated="false" style="-fx-background-color: #eeeeee;" text="Compensation Options" textFill="#1b75bc">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Top pane expanded" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
         </top>
          <center>
            <TitledPane fx:id="bTitledPane" animated="false" style="-fx-background-color: #eeeeee;" text="Other Options" textFill="#1b75bc">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Bottom pane expanded" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
         </center>
         <bottom>   
            <Button fx:id="openCloseButton" onAction="#openClose" text="Close" textAlignment="CENTER" />
         </bottom>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

And it controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TitledPane aTitledPane, bTitledPane;
    @FXML
    private Button openCloseButton;

    private final static String OPEN = "Open", CLOSE = "Close";

    @FXML
    void initialize(){
        openCloseButton.setText(OPEN);
        aTitledPane.setExpanded(false);
        bTitledPane.setExpanded(false);
    }

    @FXML
    private void openClose(){
        System.out.println(openCloseButton.getText());
        if(openCloseButton.getText().equals(OPEN)){
            openCloseButton.setText(CLOSE);
            aTitledPane.setExpanded(true);
            bTitledPane.setExpanded(true);
        }else{
            openCloseButton.setText(OPEN);
            aTitledPane.setExpanded(false);
            bTitledPane.setExpanded(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Test it using :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("xml/Main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(null);
    }
}
```

If you want that opening / closing one `TitledPane` will open / close the other without using a button, remove the button from the fxml, and bind `TitledPane.expandedProperty()` of the two `TitledPane`s in the controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TitledPane aTitledPane, bTitledPane;

    @FXML
    void initialize(){
        aTitledPane.expandedProperty().bindBidirectional(bTitledPane.expandedProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that i should make titledpanes in one VBox? Actually i am refactoring code and i already made some panels as JavaFX. So i want to use TitledPanes as JavaFX Accordion which can expand 2 more TitledPanes at once.

Comment: Not actually in one VBox.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just using VBox.

I made VBox, titledPane and VBox which contains some Btns, Labels, and so on.

```
VBox mainBox = new VBox();
TitledPane T1 = new TitledPane();
VBox content1 = new VBox();
T1.setContent(content1);
TitledPane T2 = new TitledPane();
VBox content2 = new VBox();
T2.setContent(content2);

mainBox.getChildren().addAll(T1, T2);
```

and then in MainVBox, titledPanes are shown like accordion.